# How to sort a file on multiple positions using Windows command line?

Tags: sorting, batch-file

I have an index text file, and I'm having trouble sorting it. I've been looking online for an answer, but Google hasn't pulled up anything with multi-positional searches.

Trying to do so with Unix (which would be easy), would be done as

```
sort inputfile -k1.1 -k3.3 -o outputfile
```

should accomplish the task, but trying to do so gives me Cygwin errors of already specifying the input twice (UNIX sorts are out!).

I need to sort this index file, either with Windows console applications or Perl on both positions.

Here is the input data:

> **1925699**|0003352_0050003895.pdf|**00500003895**|0003352
>   **1682628**|0003352_0050003894.pdf|**00500003894**|0003352
>   **1682628**|0003352_0050003893.pdf|**00500003893**|0003352

The desired output is:

> **1682628**|0003352_0050003893.pdf|**00500003893**|0003352
>   **1682628**|0003352_0050003894.pdf|**00500003894**|0003352
>   **1925699**|0003352_0050003895.pdf|**00500003895**|0003352

I'm currently trying to use:

```
sort/+1,7 /+32,11 < inputfile > outputfile
```

But I've failed to get this to be successful. (It only sorts the first parameter.) Again Unix is out of the question, and I can do it in Perl, but can this be done in Windows command line?

Comment: What version of DOS are you using?

Comment: i'm using windows 7

Comment: So you're not using any version of `DOS` despite using `DOS` in both your question title and body. It may help if you search Google again, this time without the term `DOS`

Comment: Version 6.1.7601 of windows. The actual batch file is using a dos sort though I thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q45575219.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "tempfile=%destdir%\tempfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,3delims=|" %%s IN ("%%a") DO (
  ECHO(%%s%%t^|%%a
 )
)
)>"%tempfile%"
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=|" %%a IN (' sort "%tempfile%" ' ) DO ECHO(%%b
)>"%outfile%"

DEL "%tempfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q45575219.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Uses a temporary file defined as %tempfile%

Read the source file, assigning each line to `%%a`. Analyse `%%a` using pipe as a delimiter and select the first and third tokens. Prefix the first and third tokens to the entire line, separated by a pipe and `echo` into a temporary file.

sort the temporary file, tokenise again on pipe, selecting the first token (before the first pipe) and the rest of the line; output only the *rest* to the destination file.

Comment: This was kind of neat-I ran it, but the output I needed was way off. that was my fault-I should have put it in the question sooner.....Any chance you can solve the current problem as is? :D

Comment: The input data you've provided generates the output described with the code I've shown. What are the symptoms of your problem? What is the format of the sourcefile? Does it contain CRLF as end of line of LF-only?

Comment: everything is using CLRLF-the output I generated had a field that was a concatenation between sorted fields, but the lines where massive. I edited everything-and now am just returning the 2 fields...

Comment: And, since I edited the wrong spots, but figured everything out-your code works perfectly. THANK YOU~~~